# Odoo Many 2 Many Selection field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to create a selection field in Odoo9. I can add an item but it does not save the name only the name of user who created it.

[image]

**My model.py looks like**

```
from openerp import models, api, fields

class ComputerItems(models.Model):
    _name = "notebook"
    items_computer = fields.Char("Items")
    ds_items = fields.Char("Items")


class ds_repair(models.Model):

    _name = "ds.repair"
    x_partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Client', required=True)
    other = fields.Char("Other", size=128)
    items = fields.Many2many('notebook',
                             'ds_items', string='Items')
```

**My model.xml**

```
<record id="view_ds_repair_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ds.repair.form</field>
        <field name="model">ds.repair</field>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Repairs">

            <sheet>
            <div class="oe_title">
                <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                <group colspan="4" col="6">
                <h1><field name="x_partner_id" placeholder="Customer Name"/></h1>
                <field name="create_date"/>

                <h2>Priority<field name="priority"/></h2>

                </group>
                 <group colspan="4" col="6">
                         <field name="computer_make"/>
                     <field name="password" colspan="2"/>
                     <field name="items"/>
                 </group>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't create any tree for you model odoo will create a costum tree for it :

first he will check the value of attribute `_rec_name` .rec_name contain the name of the field that represent the record by default the `_rec_name = "name"` so odoo will look for a field named `name` if it exists, odoo will create a tree with one field. but like in you case your Model don't have a field named name odoo will create a tree with `create_uid`. in order to tell odoo to create a tree from another field you change the value of _rec_name

```
class ModelClass(models.Model):
     _name ="model.name"
    _rec_name = "field_name"

    field_name = fields.....
```

this is good when your model have only one field but when your Model have more than one field you have two choices

if your Model needs only one tree for all kind of usage create a tree for it and odoo will always call it

if your Model can have multi tree for diffrent many2many or one2many field you can do this :

```
<field name="x2many_field_name" >
  <tree>
      <!-- your field here -->
  </tree>
 <form>
    <!-- costum form here -->
 </form>
</field>
```

if you want to use `many2many_tags` widget you need to specify the`_rec_name`

```
_rec_name = "field_name"

<field name="x2many_field_name" widget="many2many_tags" />
```

Comment: Thanks Charif that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just change like the below for the field *'items'*

```
 <field name="items" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```